# Hibernate generating SELECT before INSERT for new child entities

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a parent entity with some children entities. When saving a new parent entity and its children entities, Spring is able to call `persist` and I could see there are only some INSERT statements generated.

Problem is when I add some new children entities to an existing parent entity and save it, Spring calls `merge` instead and what I found was there were some SELECT statements generated for those new children entities before their INSERT statements.

How to avoid these extra SELECT statements?

e.g.

```
@Entity
public class MyParent {
    ...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "myParent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<MyChild> children;
}

@Entity
public class MyChild {
    ...        
}
```

and

```
MyParent myParent = buildNewParentAndChildren();
myParentRepository.save(myParent); // deep down calls persist(), generates INSERT only
```

but

```
MyParent myParent = myParentRepository.findById(1);
MyChild myChild = buildNewChild();
myParent.getMyChildren().add(myChild);
myParentRepository.save(myParent); // deep down calls merge(), generates SELECT and INSERT
```

Comment: Is there a connection from child to parent?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yes

Comment: Then provide the full mapping between the entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding an element to a collection. This has to initialize the lazy collection - therefore you get your `SELECT`.

Note, that you don't need to work with the collection at all in order to add the element. You're using an "inverse" mapping by declaring `mappedBy = "myParent"`. This means that it's the child who's responsible for persisting the association with its parent.

So what you need is:

```
MyParent myParent = myParentRepository.findById(1);
MyChild myChild = buildNewChild();
myChild.setParent(myParent);
someRepository.persist(myChild)
```

Next time you select MyParent from a different Hibernate Session, you'll get your new element in the collection.

It makes sense to add to the collection only if you intend to work with that list in the same request. But that means you do need the `SELECT`.

PS: If you get rid of Spring Data in favour of Hibernate Session or JPA EntityManager, you'd be able to eliminate `SELECT`ing MyParent too by using `session.load(1)` or `entityManager.getRerence(1)`.

Comment: Yes, using a repository of `MyChild` to save the new `myChild` does indeed skip the SELECT and only INSERT is generated! So what is the pros and cons of this method vs my original method (i.e. saving child directly vs saving parent and then cascade save the child)?

Comment: There are no cons of this approach - the way you mapped your entities suggests that you use exactly these steps. Adding to a collection is necessary only if you're _not_ using `mappedBy`.

Comment: Right ok, got it. Then is there a way to avoid SELECT when there is no `mappedBy` (i.e. uni direction)?

Comment: No, as mentioned by @Andriy Slobodyanyk in another answer, Set has to check if the newly added element already exists in the collection. For this it needs to load other elements. The only solution is to switch to another type of collection - List (which uses PersistedBag if elements aren't ordered in DB). And also as mentioned by @Andriy Slobodyanyk - be careful with Sets as `hashCode()` which relies on IDs may lead to nasty bugs when those IDs are generated _after_ adding elements to the set.

Comment: @Stanislav_Bashkyrtsev I tried your method, it works for existing `MyParent` when I try to persist a new `MyChild`, but if the parent is also new, I get error when persisting the child saying foreign reference key violation from the database because the parent hasn't been saved yet. How would you solve this?

Comment: The error that you mention implies that you didn't set the field `MyChild.parent`. You need to set it, but also you'd need to either `persist(parent)` prior to persisting the child or set up a cascade.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `Set` of children. That's fine but by its definition it should check that the newly added child wasn't present at the collection before. Consider using `List` instead.

Also, I would suggest to check [how to implement equals() and hashCode()](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/) for the entity correctly.